# Why is nothing being displayed on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The following is my code. Yet when I run it I get a blank page. Why is this the case ? Also how can I use data from hundreds of columns to make a simple interactive visual using d3 ? I would like to add that the following csv file "LoanStats3a.csv" is in the same folder.

```
 <html>
    <title>Loans</title>
<link href="../css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.12.4"></script>  
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style>
        #LoanStats3a{
           color: blueviolet;   
        }
        </style>
<body>
    <script>
        d3.csv("LoanStats3a", function (file1){
            var bg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", 5000)
                    .attr("height", 5000);

        bg.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(file1)
                    .enter()
                    .attr("width", function(d){return d.loan_amnt / 100;})
                    .attr("height", function(d) {return d.term;})
                    .attr("y", function (d,i) {return i *50;})
                    .attr("fill", function (d){"red","blue";});
    }   
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: There is nothing in your html code i.e. in body tag, which HTML markup

Comment: There is nothing in the html code that would appear on the website, as the above comment mentioned, and the files being referenced in the link and script tags are referencing a local file back a directory, so unless you have those files on your computer or you've uploaded this file to a website which go back to those directories, those files won't load.

Comment: Isnt d3 supposed to add that?

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. Are there any errors? Look at the Network tab. Do all the files load successfully?

Comment: Im getting the following error: "d3.v3.js:670 Error: <rect> attribute width: Expected length, "NaN".attrFunction @ d3.v3.js:670
41540 console messages are not shown."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because after binding the data to your empty selection, you have to `append` a rect element for each data.

Also, your attribute "fill" is incorrect.

```
bg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(file1)
    .enter()
    .append("rect") // <= You need to create a rect for each data
    .attr("width", function(d){return d.loan_amnt / 100;})
    .attr("height", function(d) {return d.term;})
    .attr("y", function (d,i) {return i *50;})
    .attr("fill", "blue");
```

If you want to change the color depending on the data, create a function and `return` something.

```
// For example
.attr("fill", function(d){return d.loan_amnt > 25000 ? "blue" : "red"});
```

Here's a JsFiddle with random data : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/m23agvwq/)

**EDIT :** If it's still not working, it's probably a problem with your data because the only thing different between our code is that I used custom data in the JsFiddle.

I notice that your csv file doesn't have the extension `.csv`, it's just `LoanStats3a` ?
You should do a `console.log(file1)`, to check if your data are correct.

Take a look at [D3 CSV](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/CSV) for how to load a csv file.

Comment: There might be a problem with your data. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `)` at the end:

```
     .attr("fill", function (d){"red","blue";});
   }  
//  ^ Here should be a )
</script>
```

It helps if you have proper indent:

```
<script>
d3.csv("LoanStats3a", function(file1) {
    var bg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 5000)
        .attr("height", 5000);

    bg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(file1)
        .enter()
        .attr("width", function(d) {
            return d.loan_amnt / 100;
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return d.term;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
            return i * 50;
        })
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
            "red", "blue"; // What is going on here?
                           // Did you for to return?
                           // return "blue";
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I fixed that yet am having the same problem.